# UIImage gradient

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimage, gradient

Well, I have an UITableView with an UIImage on each cell. Everything works fine, but now I would like to change the image and make it like the right picture of this link:

http://www.cultofmac.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Screen-Shot-2012-06-07-at-13.06.31.jpg

Every image has a kind of gradient I would really like to implement. Any suggestion to achieve it?

Comment: try to mask the layer of `UIImageView`, it will give you the same result if you are using the nice gradient image for masking.

Comment: @holex can you give me some code please, I'm quite lost in here

Comment: Make sure you composite a new image when putting a transparent gradient over your image, or your table will scroll like crap.

Comment: @escrafford what do you mean with composite a new image? It's true, I have implemented it, and it scrolls like crap

Comment: create a new image from the other two images so that there is no transparency. Every time you try scrolling, it's recalculating all the transparent portions for you. This post ought to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313023/overlay-an-image-over-another-image-in-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `ARC`:

```
UIImageView *_imageView = ...; // this will be masked
UIImage *_layerImage = [UIIMage imageNamed:@"maskImage.png"]; // mask image
CALayer *_layer = [CALayer layer];
_layer.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, _layerImage.size.width, _layerImage.size.height);
_layer.contents = (__bridge id)([_layerImage CGImage]);
[_imageView.layer setMask:_layer];
```

---

do not forget

- to include the **QuartzCore.framework**, and
- the `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` line;

---

the mask image will work with the `alpha` channel only, so where the `alpha` is `1.f` on the image, that part of the original view will be full visible, where the `alpha` is `0.f` that part of the original view will be full transparent.